# How do I convert an integer to a string in JavaScript?

Tags: string, integer

```
function seven_boom() {
var a = window.prompt("Enter Number:");
var b = Number(a) / 7;
var c = b.toString();
var d = c.includes(".");
if (d=="true") {
alert("BOOM!");
}}
```

I want to convert b to string and I tried the code above this text and its doesn't work....
Please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

`d` is a boolean, so it's value will be `true` or `false` whereas you're checking if d is a string and has value "true"

```js
function seven_boom() {
var a = window.prompt("Enter Number:");
var b = Number(a) / 7;
var c = b.toString();
var d = c.includes("."); // The output of this line is a boolean
if (d) {
alert("BOOM!");
}}

seven_boom();
```